# agsm.bst: change color of the field "Author"

Tags: bibtex, natbib

is there any way to change the color of the authors reported in the bibilography, using agsm style?
I know is not *correct*, but it would make much easier to identify the authors in  looooong bibligraphy...

Here's a minimum working example

Body.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\cite{Dante} wrote: 

Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\\
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura\\
ché la diritta via era smarrita.\\
Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura\\
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte\\
che nel pensier rinova la paura!\\

\bibliography{tempBIB}

\end{document}
```

tempBIB.bib:

```
@Article{Dante,
  Title                    = {La divina Commedia},
  Author                   = {Alighieri, Dante},
  Journal                  = {Any Journal},
  Year                     = {1312},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {1-100},
  Volume                   = {33},
  Publisher                = {Cangrande Della Scala}
}
```

I'd like to have Dante Alighieri in blue...

Comment: Where should the name be rendered in blue: in the typeset entry, the citation call-out(s), or both?

Comment: in the bibliography