# Bibliography: change author color

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, color

I'm writing because I wasn't able to find a solution nor in Google nor here. My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251725/agsm-bst-change-color-of-the-field-author), but that hasn't a solution yet. Is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316425/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-bibliography-item-when-using-biblatex-with-beamer) too, but it uses beamer and I'm not.

My question is: how can I change the color of the author (*only the author*) item in my bibliography, which is formatted as follows:

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,dashed=false,language=italian]{biblatex}`

This works fine, but in the Bibliography at the end of the document, I would have the author colored. I mean, only the author, nothing more in the document, which should remain the same.

I tried by adding `\textcolor` to the item in the bibliography file:

```
@article{addicott2006networks,
 title={Networks, organizational learning and knowledge management: NHS cancer networks},
 author={\textcolor{red}{Addicott, Rachael} and McGivern, Gerry and Ferlie, Ewan},
 journal={Public Money and Management},
 volume={26},
 number={2},
 pages={87--94},
 year={2006},
 publisher={Taylor & Francis},
 langid={italian},
 }
```

The result was perfect for the bibliography, **but** it modifies also the color of the reference in the text, as in the following images:

[image: Author Colored in the Bibliography]

[image]

Does anyone know how to *just color the author in the bibliography* and *leave unaltered* in the text?

(*I know I'm not providing any MWE, honestly I don't think is necessary in this case. But if needed I will post it.*)

Thank you for your time,
R.

UPDATE: **sorry** guys, here the MWE for what I'm trying to figure out:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,dashed=false,language=italian]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Reference I don't want to be coloured \citep{addicott2006networks}

\printbibliography[title={Bibliografia}]

\end{document}

 @article{addicott2006networks,
 title={Networks, organizational learning and knowledge management: NHS cancer networks},
 author={\textcolor{red}{Addicott, Rachael} and McGivern, Gerry and Ferlie, Ewan},
 journal={Public Money and Management},
 volume={26},
 number={2},
 pages={87--94},
 year={2006},
 publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
 langid={italian},
 }
```

Comment: Not necessary in what sense? You mean that if somebody really wants to help you, they might be able to figure out what you're doing? Of course. But (1) somebody might be willing to help, but not that enthusiastic, and (2) they might not figure it out, guess incorrectly and just waste their time. Better chance of being useful if they spend their efforts helping somebody who really wants the help. (I figure you are mildly interested in an answer, but not especially bothered if you don't get one.)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want? Your title and the wording in your question suggests to me (maybe wrongly) that you want to colour all authors. But in your screenshot you explicitly colour only one author in the list.

Comment: A MWE is always necessary! For example, your `publisher={Taylor & Francis}` surely is an error, it should be `publisher={Taylor \& Francis}`.

Comment: Regarding the need for an MWE: Some questions are entirely clear and can be answered without an MWE. Other questions need an MWE because they are about specific behaviour caused by a particular piece of code. Sometimes people think their questions don't need an MWE, yet it is needed in order to assess the situation. There are several ways to achieve different things and it is not always entirely clear which was used without an MWE. But even questions that need no MWE at all can still benefit from one. It allows helpers to directly start working on the solution ...

Comment: ... instead of having to spend time building the environment in which it should be used. Plus, this allows those answering questions to test their solution in the exact environment they are going to be used. The time needed to provide a good code environment is much less for those asking than those answering. Take your question as an example, you have given us quite some snippets of code. It would take you just a few more minutes (if at all) to complete it to an MWE that resembles your document. But for us it might be more complicated.

Comment: I'm glad to see that our demanding an MWE has resulted in one. Thank you. Can you answer my question about what specifically you want? I'm not sure if you want to (1) colour all authors, (2) colour one specific author (Rachael Addicott, say), or (3) (as David thinks) colour only the first author.

Comment: @cfr sorry. I'm really interested in understanding a possibile solution to my answer, if not I wouldn't have asked anything. Yesterday night was late and I was really tired, sorry again.

Comment: @moewe thank you for your answers and explanation, I provided the MWE, I understood my english is not as well as I believe! And yes, you got it: I need color for **all** the authors in the Bibliography, not just one as in my (stupid) screenshot.

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank you for your answer. Honestly I take bibtex code directly from Google Scholar, never had problems with it. Actually I changed the `&` into `\&` and nothing changed. Probably because `publisher` is not displayed in the bibliography at all?

Comment: One last question. Do you want to retain the name order of 'Last, First' for first name and then 'First Last'. Or do you want all names 'First Last' or 'Last First'?

Comment: Please feel free to ask me as many questions as you need. I would have to retain the Last First combination both for the Text and the Bibliography.

Comment: Mhhh, that I don't understand. Currently in-text citations only show the last name. In the bibliography the first name of a list is treated differently to the following ones: The first name is in `Last, First` format and the other names (if any) in 'First Last'. What exact format do you want?

Comment: @moewe ok I understood: in the screenshot above, the situation is as you described (in-text only `LastName` and in the bibliography first `Last, First` and the others `First, Last`). BUT in the bibliography I see the first author in `Last, First` **as** the others (second, third..) authors. Is that related to the code you provide below?

Comment: Yes, my code shows all authors in 'Last, First' format. Is that OK with you or do you want the behaviour of your screenshot back?

Comment: @CarLaTeX `publisher` is ignored for `@article`s in all standard styles and most styles I know. Of course when printed it will cause problems as you noted.

Comment: @moewe No no is ok like this, I really prefer all the authors in the same format. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want 'Last, First' names where the comma within the name is to be coloured yet the delimiter between names (either a comma or 'and') is not to be coloured, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,dashed=false,language=italian]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{addicott2006networks,
  title={Networks, organizational learning and knowledge management: NHS cancer networks},
  author={Addicott, Rachael and McGivern, Gerry and Ferlie, Ewan},
  journal={Public Money and Management},
  volume={26},
  number={2},
  pages={87-94},
  year={2006},
  langid={italian},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{colour-family-given}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:colour:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:colour:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro*{name:colour:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \textcolor{red}{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
         \ifcapital
           {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
           {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
         \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot 
       \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \textcolor{red}{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct}%  
       \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{colour-family-given}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\autocite{addicott2006networks}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

`sortname` is the name format used in author-year/author-title-like styles for the labelname.

Comment: OOOH yes! It works like a charm @moewe! Thank you! One more question related to your code, please: if I understood well, the code assign a color to the name and a color to the family name, isn't it? One of the most difficult things to understand for me is the `test and test` part.

Comment: @user51937 The code is a copy of the original definitions from `biblatex.def` with `\textcolor{red}` added in the right places. It uses the same colour for all name parts. It was just necessary to define two macros due to the way the macros work.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want just the first author coloured, then you can do it by creating a new name format based off `family-given/given-family` and then aliasing the `author` name format to it. You could create a similar name format alias for `editor` if you needed it. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,dashed=false,language=italian]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{addicott2006networks,
  title={Networks, organizational learning and knowledge management: NHS cancer networks},
  author={Addicott, Rachael and McGivern, Gerry and Ferlie, Ewan},
  journal={Public Money and Management},
  volume={26},
  number={2},
  pages={87-94},
  year={2006},
  langid={italian},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameFormat{coloured-family-given/given-family}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\textcolor{red}{%
     \ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{coloured-family-given/given-family}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\autocite{addicott2006networks}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! It took ten minutes for me to understand something about the code you provided, I'm quite autodidact with LaTeX, sorry.

Actually I didn't explain really well what I want to achieve. I try to explain better: I need to color all the authors, without the "e"/"and", just really names and surnames.

Comment: Note that with standard author-year/author-title styles you can use `sortname` to access the labelname format in bibliographies. This means you don't have to redefine `author`, `editor` and `translator`.

Comment: @user51937 Sorry, I might have been a bit unclear. You could just do `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{coloured-family-given/given-family}`, and would not have to alias `author`, `editor` and `translator` (as was done for `author` and mentioned for `editor`).#