# How to color labelnames in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, color

I would like to have the names of authors/editors (editors only if no authors given) in a certain color (e.g. red).

---

```
\documentclass[%
]{scrbook}%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @InCollection{DelPercio2014,
  author    = {Del Percio, Alfonso and Reisigl, Martin},
  title     = {Angewandte Diskursforschung},
  booktitle = {Diskursforschung - Ein interdisziplinäres Handbuch},
  publisher = {transcript Verlag},
  isbn      = {9783839427224},
  date      = {2014},
  location  = {Bielefeld},
}

@InCollection{Angermuller2014c,
  author    = {Angermuller, Johannes and Macgilchrist, Felicitas},
  title     = {Einleitung: Konzepte und Kontroversen der Diskurstheorie},
  booktitle = {Diskursforschung: ein interdisziplinäres Handbuch},
  editor = {Hans Wurst},
  publisher = {transcript Verlag},
  pages     = {17--20},
  date      = {2014},
  origdate  = {1999}, 
  location  = {Bielefeld},
}

@Book{Motakef2015,
  title     = {Prekarisierung},
  publisher = {transcript Verlag},
  author    = {Motakef, Mona},
  isbn      = {978-3-8376-2566-0},
  date      = {2015},
  location  = {Bielefeld},
  url       = {http://www.transcript-verlag.de/978-3-8376-2566-0/prekarisierung},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Titel}
\footcite[23-44]{Motakef2015}
\footcite[19\psq]{Angermuller2014c}
\footcite[123]{DelPercio2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Right now it looks like this

[image]

but it should be colored as seen here:

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364156/bibliography-change-author-color/364192#364192